# Publishing Website with VS 2012 - But need to ignore Wordpress blog folder on server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

I have a site that works and publishes fine.

The site has a "blog" folder that contains my wordpress blog.

I want to be able to check off the "Remove additional files at destination" checkbox during publish so my servers stays clean and doesn't get bloated with old DLL files/images/old pages....

I have the following in my .pubxml file:

```
   <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifes>AddCustomSkipRules</AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifes>
```

and then after the '< /PropertyGroup> tag I have:

```
<Target Name="AddCustomSkipRules">
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
    <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
    <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\blog\\.*</AbsolutePath>
    <XPath>
    </XPath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
    <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
    <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\blog\\.*</AbsolutePath>
    <XPath>
    </XPath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
</ItemGroup>
```

It still deletes the blog folder.

What am I doing wrong?